# How to check specific phrases in text are present with regex

Tags: regex

I want to match phrases in a string with regex

Example

log:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, bla bla, something
>   something

I want a regex expression that can match ex. `"quick brown"`, `"over the"` and possibly even more phrases. So I can check that there's a match, and if so do some stuff.

I want it to give a match if all the given "phrases" are present but not if only one is present within my log.

For example if I want to search for `"quick brown"` and `"over the"` in the log above I want it to give a match.

But it shouldn't match if the log was

> "The quick brown fox jumps over something the lazy dog, bla bla,
>   something something"

because it can't match both `"quick brown"` and `"over the"`.

It also shouldn't give a match if the log said

> "The quick brownest fox jumps over the lazy dog, bla bla, something
>   something"

because `"quick brown"` and `"over the"` is there but "quick brown" ends on "est" so it shouldn't match that either.

I tried (`quick brown\b|over the\b`) but that doesn't quite do it for me, because I still get a match if one of the words aren't present

It has to be regex because the framework I'm using takes a regex expression as a parameter

I know it's possible to achieve the same with some code, but that's not an option in my case. It has to be regex.

Comment: Dont need regex for that. A simple `Contains` check with suffice. You can loop through your list of 'phrases' and if there is a match do something. Gvie it a go, come back if you get stuck and bring your code with you

Comment: What should be matched in `"This question is horribly posted and shows no research at all"`?

Comment: It has to be regex because the framework I'm using takes a regex expression as a parameter

Comment: So.... if it has to be regex, then regex is `"quick brown"` or `"over the"`. There is nothing special about matching a bit of text

Comment: But it has to be able to match a phrase where both are present. (quick brown|over the) seems to work

Comment: So what's the problem then if you have the answer already...

Comment: But why shouldn´t `for jumps` or `lazy dog` or even `The quick brown fox` be matched? I can´t see the logic that choses what to match and what not.

Comment: I had been searching for the answer for over an hour, and just when I posted the question I accidentally found the answer... Figures

Comment: @HimBromBeere I want to search for specifc phrases in a text. The quick brown fox sentence was just an example.

Comment: The question here is: what *is* a phrase in your world? How is it characterized? How should an algorithm detect where one phrase begins and where it ends?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I edited the question now. I hope it's more clear what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: @musefan it seems that (quick brown|over the) didn't quite do it for me since I get a match when one is present but not the other, and I don't want that

Comment: I´m still not sure what "It has to be regex because the framework I'm using takes a regex expression as a parameter" means. Can you show the calling code?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's for JsonLog
<logger name="a">
        <onceOnly regex="(quick brown\b|over the\b)" />
</logger>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124050/discussion-between-hafax-and-himbrombeere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works, after trying alot of different things

```
(\bquick brown\b).*(\bover the\b)
```

It has a match on

> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, bla bla, something
>   something"

But not

> "The quick brown fox jumps over something the lazy dog, bla bla,
>   something something"

And not

> "The quick brownest fox jumps over the lazy dog, bla bla, something
>   something"

If you don't care about the order of the phrases you can use this

```
(\bquick brown\b).*(\bover the\b)|(\bover the\b).*(\bquick brown\b)
```

The expression checks if `quick brown` and `over the` is there with anything in between.

You can also do

```
(\bquick brown\b).+?(\bover the\b)
```

That will give multiple matches if `quick brown` and `over the` is there multiple times.

In my case it makes no difference but it might for others

Comment: How does this match "The quick brown fox jumps over something the lazy dog, bla bla, something something"? Anyway isn´t this exactly what you were looking for? Does this solution work or not? You may use https://regex101.com for regex-testing as well.

Comment: Yes this is the solution I was looking for, I edited the answer to clarify, I made a mistake before - I tested using http://regexr.com/